# MSBuild: Do not generate class library config files

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I've created a custom workflow for my build process in TFS that is using the MSBuild activity.

For some reason in the output folder I'm getting config files for all of my class library projects.  Since I only need the app config file for project I'm actually building, is there a command line argument to prevent MSBuild from creating the [library].dll.config files in the output directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any msbuild arguments that caused this behavior, so I just gave up and added this to the end of the csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DeleteAfterBuild Include="$(OutDir)*.dll.config" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(DeleteAfterBuild)" />
  </Target>
```